# Magento Events. Catch static block rendering or specified block rendering

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

I  have a module which adds little piiece of code to specified static blocks - meaning that there are 2 filters:

1. static blocks only
2. only some of them, which are specified.

Currently I have an observer, which catches abstract_html_after event and checkes whether this is a static block at all and whether this block is in specified block list. If so then it adds this little html addon to the block.

The problem is: this algorythm slows down system horrifically.

What might be the solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no CMS block specific event you can use that narrows down your event scope.
You can't even use the `cms_block_load_after` event on the cms/block model to do that, because in `Mage_Cms_Model_Block` no `$_eventPrefix` is set, so you are stuck with `core_abstract_load_after`.

The only solution is to rewrite the cms/block block or model class and either dispatch a custom event there, or just add your content directly in the rewritten class.

Comment: What would be the best option? To rewrite class or to implement additional observer which will fire cms_block event? In both ways I have to check whether this is cms block or some other block.

Comment: Implementing an additional observer would also require a rewrite. I think I would rewrite the cms/block model class if it is for a specific project.

Comment: The thing is that this is important part of module. Why additional observer is rewriting?

Comment: Because there is no event specific to that block that allows you to do what you want. So, you would have to rewrite the block and then add the call to Mage::dispatchEvent() yourself. But, since you are already rewriting the block, you might as well add the required logic directly in the new concrete class you specify in the rewrite. Adding an event would make it easier for other modules to participate, and add a way out of future conflicts.